# My nginx rewrite is downloading the php file

Tags: php, nginx, rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule I'm trying:

```
            location / {
                    index index.php index.html;
                    rewrite  ^/test$  /test.php  break;
            }
```

And I also have:

```
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                    include         fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/sites/default$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_index   index.php;
            }
```

Normal php files work ok, but it seems my redirect is just downloading the php file I'm redirecting to, rather than parsing it.

What am I missing? I got the file to load, instead of download by putting the fastcgi stuff in the first location block, but it still didn't parse as php.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change `break` to `last`.

Because the new URL will need to be processed by a different `location`, you need to have nginx restart processing for the new rewritten URL, which is only done when you use `last` in the `rewrite` rule.

See [the docs](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) for a fuller explanation.